# Average of non contiguous range in other sheets

Tags: google-sheets, average, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

As you can see in the images I have one "Main" sheet and some other sheets.

I already made a formula that:

1. Reference another sheet (which name's is in a cell)
2. Extract an array of non-contiguous cells (each 10 starting from an explicit cell)
3. Compute the average.

---

```
=AVERAGEIF(ArrayFormula(mod((row(indirect($A$14&"!H3"))- 
 row(indirect($A$14&"!H3")));10));0;indirect($A$14&"!H3"))
```

The problem is that this formula can't be dragged, because of the reference H3 is a string and doesn't change by itself.

I have also another formula:

```
=AVERAGEIF(ArrayFormula(mod((row(ns0.5!H3)-row(ns0.5!H3));10));0;ns0.5!H3)
```

Which is the same the problem is that here I have to change the sheet's name (which is contained in column A)

So I'm asking for a formula (or a script) which:

1. Change by itself the name of the referred sheet using a cell content
2. Change by itself the column/row reference when dragged

I report the image of the main sheet and the image of one sheet (the `ns0.5`)

[image: Main Sheet]

[image: ns0.5]

EDIT:

[image: Formula in the comment of player01]

[image: Datas]

As you can see 0.4547 is not the average between 0.4547 and 0.4493

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can free the **H3** like this:

```
=AVERAGEIF(ARRAYFORMULA(MOD((
 ROW(INDIRECT($A$14&"!"&ADDRESS(ROW(H3); COLUMN(H3); 4)))-
 ROW(INDIRECT($A$14&"!"&ADDRESS(ROW(H3); COLUMN(H3); 4)))); 10)); 0;
     INDIRECT($A$14&"!"&ADDRESS(ROW(H3); COLUMN(H3); 4)))
```

Comment: Ok thanks, it works, but I noticed that there is no the ArrayFormula, I'm trying to add it but without results... How can I add the ArrayFormula part?

Comment: I trust you, but google sheets doesn't help: (see the edit)

Comment: Sorry but the update is exactly the same that I have in the edit

Comment: This is the correct formula: 

`=AVERAGEIF(ArrayFormula(mod((row(ns0.5!H3:H)-row(ns0.5!H3:H));10));0;ns0.5!H3:H)`
`=AVERAGEIF(ArrayFormula(mod((row(indirect($A$14&"!H3:H"))- 
 row(indirect($A$14&"!H3:H")));10));0;indirect($A$14&"!H3:H"))`

Comment: @NooneBug `=AVERAGEIF(ArrayFormula(mod((row(ns0.5!H3:H)-row(ns0.5!H3:H)),10)),0,ns0.5!H3:H) =AVERAGEIF(ArrayFormula(mod((row(indirect($A$14&"!"&ADDRESS(ROW(H3); COLUMN(H3); 4)))- row(indirect($A$14&"!"&ADDRESS(ROW(H3); COLUMN(H3); 4)))),10)),0,indirect($A$14&"!"&ADDRESS(ROW(H3); COLUMN(H3); 4)))`

Comment: Thanks to player01 I solved in this way:

In the sheet ns0.5 I computed (in a cell XY) the average with

=AVERAGE(FILTER(H3:H; MOD(ROW(H3:H)-3; 10)=0))
In the main sheet I refer XY extracting so the average from another sheet

Thanks a lot @player01 ;)